# How to run multiple commands in Azure Container Instance using yaml file

Tags: azure

I have created a Azure Container Instance using a yml file where in, I gave a command to run.

```
      command:
      - python
      - Location to Python file inside the container
```

I have also attached the Azure File Share as volume so that the, output of the command will be copied to the volume. The container instance gets created successfully and the command runs  but the output is not copied to Azure File Share. When i checked in Azure CLI, the status of container is succeeded and the state shows of container is in "waiting".

I tried connecting to the Container using "exec" command in iteractive mode but the terminal was blank for a couple of minutes and there was no response later.

```
az container exec -g RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME  --name CONTAINER_NAME --exec-command "/bin/bash
```

How to connect to the container in interactive mode and why is command output not copied to Azure File Share ?

Comment: Did you try adding `#!/usr/bin/python` header to your Python file and then only have this file in the command section?

Comment: Thanks @Kai Walter . It works now after adding the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this header to your Python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and then just execute this script on the container:

```
az container exec -g RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME  --name CONTAINER_NAME --exec-command "/root/your-python-script"
```

Comment: Thank you @Kai Walter